# jquery - setting the url after the hash

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I'd like if I could click a link with class "query" and have it's id attribute come after the hash. For example, a link that looks like this:

`<a href="#" id="members" class="query">Members</a>`

When clicked would change the url from `example.com/users` to `example.com/users#members`.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('.query').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Right now clicking the link just moves the url to `example.com/members`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `hash` property:

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it silly to have the id attribute come from the hash?  Why not just ...  Is it unreasonable to do this?  Anyway, you can do this:

```
$(".query").click(function () {
   window.location.hash = this.id;
   return false; // prevent default link follow
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location.href`